# Does the Reactor Vessels upgrade require the reactors to be operational?

Tags: kittens-game

I'm considering investing in my first reactor, but I'm not sure yet if I will be able to keep it continuously powered with uranium.  I'm wondering about the [Reactor Vessel](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=workshop&par=24) upgrade.  It says:

> Every reactor improves ship potential by 5%

Will this bonus still apply even if the reactors are powered off, either manually or due to a lack of uranium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Being on or off doesn't affect the bonus, it just counts the total number of reactors.